# Python3 Base64 Encode PyDes 3DES Object

Tags: python-3.x, 3des

Hi I am trying to create a function whereby a token is generated by the server that utilises 3DES which is then Base64 encoded and sent to a client application.

I am trying to use `pyDes` to encypt the string using a key and then base64 encode that value to be sent.

I have tried casting the object to bytes, strings etc but I just  get various errors, similar to below.

Is what I am trying to do even feasible or am I going down a rabbit hole with this solution?

```
import pyDes
import base64
key1 = b"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx"
data = bytes("messagepart1" + "messagepart2", encoding='utf8')
k = pyDes.triple_des(key1, pyDes.ECB, b"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=pyDes.PAD_PKCS5)
# e = k.decrypt(data)
print(base64.b64encode(bytes(k)))
```

Error:

```
python3 triple_des.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "triple_des.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(base64.b64encode(bytes(k)))
TypeError: cannot convert 'triple_des' object to bytes
```

Comment: `pyDes.triple_des` (or `.des`) returns an _object_ on which you can, and should, call the `.encrypt` or `.decrypt` method as needed. You want to do `e = k.encrypt(data)` and then for your case `b64encode(e)`. See http://whitemans.ca/des.html as linked from pypi.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!